# Check For Matches And Import Data Into Specific Cells From An External Source

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

We are trying to track some online marketing metrics and I'm having some trouble. I have 2 tables in different tabs (one imports data from several external data sources, ultimately we want this to be a series of google sheets) and one is the working table.

I have rows on the imported data with month and other attributes defining the data and in the working data these are columns. The working data has a lot of other cells too that are not there with calculations, etc.

What I need to do is to check on the working sheet which month (for example) we are in, then go to the working data and scan all the data for matches with that month. Then I want to consolidate each of the data parameters into the working sheet. Ideally I wouldn't even have to import all the external data into a tab  on the working spreadsheet, if I could find a way to work where it would check the external documents for the matches that would be great. The structure of the data in the external documents is the same as displayed here fore the imported data.

[image: imported data example]

Note that in this case it is month but it could be anything random so DATE functions wouldn't work.

[image: Working Sheet - Reconcilliation]

So I want to pickup the data from the external source above, and insert in the relevant places. But while the months will not change, other data can change the order in which is imported so we need to check that the headers from picture 2 match the row labels from the imported data.

I hope that makes sense. I would really appreciate any help. Was up until 4 AM trying to figure this out and I would hate to go back to my boss saying he's gonna need to get someone else to do this as I can't. :/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved this with a INDEX(array, MATCH(),MATCH()) function. First I selected the answer array from the cells with the info I wanted then used the MATCH Function to match the row and the columns I wanted in the matrix.

This created another problem where no answer existed as it threw an error so I had to envelop the whole expression in an IFERROR function.

The final solution was like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table_Query_from_Excel_Files,MATCH(!H1:I1&A1,INDEX(Table_Query_from_Excel_Files[Month]&Table_Query_from_Excel_Files[User location],,),0),MATCH(!A1,Table_Query_from_Excel_Files[#Headers],0)), 0)
```